# Кнопка Free-kassa в телеграм бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Всем добрый день. Делаю телеграм бота на Python. Функционал такой: бот отправляет сообщение-кнопку. Эта кнопка - ссылка, т.е. пользователь при нажатии на кнопку переносится на страницу free-kassa и оплачивает товар (в моём случае товар - это подписка). Но возникает ошибка при работе с free-kassa. Чтобы получить эту ссылку, free-kassa требует, чтобы на моём сайте была кнопка фрикасы (в моём случае сайт - это бот в телеграме...). Я пишу код для бота на Python в Pycharm. Код кнопки мне дают написанный на PHP. Как мне засунуть эту кнопку в своего бота? и куда? Бот присылает сообщение, а под ним 3 кнопки-ссылки - все три ведут на фрикасу. Нужно каким-то образом эту кнопку засунуть в телеграм бота. Может это делается очень просто, но почему-то информации нигде не нашел, техподдержка не помогла. Подскажите пожалуйста. Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Вам нужно у технической поддержки точно узнать поддерживают ли они подобную реализацию их сервиса. Если вы не можете понять ответ от тех. поддержки, продублируйте основную мысль в этот вопрос и можно будет подумать всем вместе.

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую так и сделать

Comment: Разобрались? Интересно решение.